# Accessing Array Elements in Reverse Order Using the Minus Sign (-) in Julia

Tags: julia

In Python, the last element of a list can be accessed using list[-1]. However, in Julia, accessing the last element is done through list[end]. This syntax increases the complexity of the algorithm I am working on. Is it possible to redefine this default behavior in Julia to access array elements in reverse order using the (-) sign? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Without further details, it is unclear how Julia's indexing syntax would significantly increase the complexity of your algorithm.

Anyway, one option could be to simply write a method which accesses an `Array` by first converting the index if it is negative:

```
julia> mygetindex(A, i) = A[i < 0 ? lastindex(A) + i + 1 : i]
mygetindex (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mygetindex([1, 2, 3, 4], -1)
4
```

As for modifying the behaviour using the square bracket syntax `A[i]`, you could define a wrapper type for an `Array` and just implement the indexing interface as described [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#Indexing). A quick example:

```
struct MyWierdArray
    a
end

Base.getindex(A::MyWierdArray, i::Int) = getindex(A.a, i < 0 ? lastindex(A.a) + i + 1 : i)
```

Gives you just about what you need to do this:

```
julia> A = MyWierdArray([1, 2, 3, 4])
MyWierdArray([1, 2, 3, 4])

julia> A[-1]
4
```

But that seems like a lot of writing, potentially confusing, and for very little gain.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the answer is type unstable.

A type stable code for `@btime $A[-1]` benchmarks to be over 30 times faster.

Hence it should be:

```
struct MyWierdArray2{T}
   a::T
end
```

You might also enforce that `T isa AbstractVector`:

```
 struct MyWierdArray2{T <: AbstractVector}
    a::T
end
```

The `getindex` does not need to be changed so it still is:

```
Base.getindex(A::MyWierdArray2, i::Int) = getindex(A.a, i < 0 ? lastindex(A.a) + i + 1 : i)
```

Benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime A[-1] setup=(A=MyWierdArray([1,2,3,4]))
  53.245 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
4

julia> @btime A[-1] setup=(A=MyWierdArray2([1,2,3,4]))
  1.700 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
4
```

Comment: yes, ok. Anyway, I think you shouldn't do this, as is written in the answer